# Spectral analysis of a $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory

We have the matrix

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{3} & 3 \\ 3 &\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I want to find the spectral analysis of that matrix, i.e., write $A$ as a linear combination of projections into eigenspaces.

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm 2\sqrt{3}$. The eigenvectors are $\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{3} \\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\1\end{pmatrix}$. How can we continue to get the projections?

Comment: How can we find the projection of $A$ (an object of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$) on a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (i.e., the eigenspaces)? Maybe, are you looking for the diagonalization of $A$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'find spectral analysis'. Said that way, the question maked no sense. Spectral decomposition of $A $?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your vectors are orthogonal. Check $P\propto uu^{T}$.

Comment: Do  you mean the following? $$P=\lambda_1v_1v_1^T+\lambda_2v_2v_2^T=-2\sqrt{3}\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{3} \\1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{3} \\1\end{pmatrix}^T+2\sqrt{3}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\1\end{pmatrix}^T$$

Comment: This is true if your vectors are normalized. This is why I used $\propto$ instead of equality. A little fix and you're done.

Comment: Ahh ok!! So we divide each by the norm and we get \begin{align*}P& =-2\sqrt{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{3} \\1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{3} & 1\end{pmatrix}+2\sqrt{3}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 1\end{pmatrix} \\ & =-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{3} \\1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{3} & 1\end{pmatrix}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 \\\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 &\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}\end{align*} right?

Comment: Exactly! See indeed https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-(sqrt(3)%2F2)(%7B3,-sqrt(3)%7D,%7B-sqrt(3),1%7D)%2B(sqrt(3)%2F2)(%7B1,sqrt(3)%7D,%7Bsqrt(3),3%7D).

Comment: I tried to apply that also at an other example, $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \sqrt{3} \\  \sqrt{3} & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ We have the eigenvalus $-2,2$ and the eigenvectors $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{3} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. These two are orthogonal. We divide each vector by its length, i.e.,  both by $2$ nd so we get $$P=-2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}^T+2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{3} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{3} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}^T$$

Comment: In Wolfram I don't get the initial matrix $A$. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar Because your eigenvectors and eigenvalues are wrong. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%7B1,sqrt(3)%7D,%7Bsqrt(3),1%7D).

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot a minus, the matrix is $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \sqrt{3} \\  \sqrt{3} & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: You normalized just one vector in each multiplication.

Comment: Ohh yes!!! Thank you for the hint!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar Note that you can avoid the square roots: $(v/\lVert v\rVert)(v/\lVert v\rVert)^T=(vv^T)/(v^Tv)$. Note, too, that when the eigenspaces are not orthogonal, you’ll have to do something else to compute the projectors.